# Delete row in mysql and associated from folder

Tags: php, mysql

I have admin panel where I show rows from database with ability to delete them. 
Here is how I delete them delete.php

**UPDATE**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];

$name = "SELECT name FROM images WHERE id=$id";
$name=mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
$name=$name['name'];

if ($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);

    $stmt->execute();
    unlink("../upload/" . $name);
    $stmt->close();
}

else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
$con->close();

header("Location: images_delete.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: images_delete.php");
}
```

Then I must open 'Upload' form to delete the image which I deleted from mysql. How can I make when I delete that image from mysql also to delete from folder?

In mysql I store path and name of the image.

**UPDATE: Here is final version of the file which is working-> delete file from folder and record in DB**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{

$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id" or die(mysqli_error($con));
$res = mysqli_query($con, $name);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$name1 = $row['name'];
//print_r($name1);
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $folder = 'C:\wamp\www\upload';
    chown($folder,465);

    //var_dump($name1);
    unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/$name1");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("id",$id);`, not `$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);`

Comment: Why `"id"` ? I get integer there thats why I put `"i"`. Can you explain pls?

Comment: it is  `$stmt->bind_param(1,$id);` none of the 2

Comment: I meant better is to use placeholders. change your query a bit: `prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")` and after that use `$stmt->bind_param(":id",$id);`

Comment: Hm, ok thank's. I'm not advanced in prepared statements and still learning it. and what about my upload stmt ..i gues is wrong also in that case: `"INSERT INTO images (caption, name, size, type, file_path, alt, img_category) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";` and `$conn->bind_param("ssissss",$caption, $myFile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path, $alt, $category);`

Comment: You're mixing your MySQL APIs. `mysql_fetch_assoc` and other `mysqli_*` functions that you have do NOT mix. @Goro Change to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes I'm aware of this and I already changed it! Thank's for pointing it. So now is working and image is also deleted from folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `unlink($your_image_path)` to delete image

Comment: use this code after successful deletion of entry from DB in your if condition `if ($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
{`

Comment: He has the to select the image_name first, before deletion.

Comment: Absolutely right, First fetch image name from DB then delete from DB, if delete success then use `unlink()` to delete from folder

Comment: Updated my question. So I show also name of the image which I want to delete?

Comment: Something like this before `if(...)` -> `$name = $_GET['name'];` and right after execute and before close stmt `$stmt->execute(); unlink("../upload/" . $name); $stmt->close();` ?

Comment: wrong...do like this..`SELECT img_name FROM images WHERE id=$_G['id']`. Here you will get image name, then delete entry form DB then `unlink('image_path_here/$img_name');`

Comment: I'm more confused now. Where will be this? But with `$name = $_GET['name'];` I will get the name from show.php like `$id` or I'm again wrong?

Comment: `$id = $_GET['id'];` just after this

Comment: yes right....whts result, is it working....Does your name field of DB contain extension of image like img.jpg/img.gif like this

Comment: `$name = "SELECT name FROM images WHERE id=$id"`
`$name=mysql_fetch_assoc($name);` 
`$name=$name['name'];`
make this changes plz

Comment: Good...Try to execute code, check image is deleted or not

Comment: Deleted from DB but still is in folder. Do I need to take also path from DB or the name is enought? I store the path in `file_path` row.. but I think the name only is good since I make `$name = "../upload/". $name`

Comment: just name is enough, but check is it taking correct path of image, u plz create 2 lines of code to delete file in another php file just to verify image is deleting or not, just sample code...
`unset('C:\image\ex.jpg');` and check is it working well or not..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50684/discussion-between-amol-and-goro)